# How can I globally increase a value in python by the parameter in a function?

Tags: python

The variable genreIndex will only increase inside the function, not globally. Anyway to make it global. I tried assigning a global variable to index.

```
genreList = [4.25, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4.35, 5, 4.5, 3.75, 3.75, 4.75, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4.75, 3.75, 2.75, 5, 5, 4, 3.5, 5, 3.25, 2.5, 5, 3, 4.75, 5, 4, 5, 2, 5, 5, 5, 2.5, 3.25, 0, 4.25, 4, 5, 0, 5, 4.25, 4, 5, 2.5, 5, 4.5, 3.5, 3.25, 4, 1, 3.5, 4, 5, 3, 2.75, 4.5, 3, 5, 0.5, 3, 4, 0, 3.5, 3.25, 3.5, 5, 4, 5, 3.5, 5, 3.5, 3, 4.5, 4.5, 5, 3, 4.75, 3.5, 3.75, 4.5, 4, 3.5, 3.75, 4.5, 5, 5, 3.5, 4.5, 5, 4, 4.5, 5, 4, 3.75, 5, 4.5, 4.5, 3.75, 3.5, 3.75, 3.5, 5, 4.5, 5, 3.5, 4.25, 5, 4, 3.25, 3.5, 2.5, 4, 3.5, 3.75, 0, 3.5, 5, 4.5, 0, 4, 4.25, 5, 4, 3.5, 1.5, 2.5]
genreIndex = 0
def reset(index, list):
    global x
    index = index + 1
    x = index
    print(x)
    if index > (len(list) - 1):
        index = 0
 
    if index < 0:
        index = len(list)
    print(list[x])
    
reset(genreIndex, genreList)
reset(genreIndex, genreList)
reset(genreIndex, genreList)
```

Comment: Variables are passed by value, not by reference. Assigning to `index` has no effect on the variable, and there's no way to make it do that.

Comment: The function should return the new value, and you can do `genreIndex = reset(...)`

Comment: Don't use global mutable state, as a general advise. That said, you managed to do this with `x`, so what keeps you from doing the same with the other var?

Comment: Do your want your function to be used generally for multiple lists / indexes, or is it specifically targeted to `genreIndex`?

Comment: @tdelany - multiple lists/indexes

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 0):

To make `genreIndex` a global variable and ensure its changes are reflected globally, you need to declare it as a global variable within your function like:

```
genreList = [4.25, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4.35, 5, 4.5, 3.75, 3.75, 4.75, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4.75, 3.75, 2.75, 5, 5, 4, 3.5, 5, 3.25, 2.5, 5, 3, 4.75, 5, 4, 5, 2, 5, 5, 5, 2.5, 3.25, 0, 4.25, 4, 5, 0, 5, 4.25, 4, 5, 2.5, 5, 4.5, 3.5, 3.25, 4, 1, 3.5, 4, 5, 3, 2.75, 4.5, 3, 5, 0.5, 3, 4, 0, 3.5, 3.25, 3.5, 5, 4, 5, 3.5, 5, 3.5, 3, 4.5, 4.5, 5, 3, 4.75, 3.5, 3.75, 4.5, 4, 3.5, 3.75, 4.5, 5, 5, 3.5, 4.5, 5, 4, 4.5, 5, 4, 3.75, 5, 4.5, 4.5, 3.75, 3.5, 3.75, 3.5, 5, 4.5, 5, 3.5, 4.25, 5, 4, 3.25, 3.5, 2.5, 4, 3.5, 3.75, 0, 3.5, 5, 4.5, 0, 4, 4.25, 5, 4, 3.5, 1.5, 2.5]

def reset(index_var, lst):
    global x
    x = index_var + 1
    if x >= len(lst):
        x = 0
    print(lst[x])

x = 0
reset(x, genreList)
reset(x, genreList)
reset(x, genreList)
```

Output:

```
4
5
5
```

Comment: But I want it to work with any variable, not just genreIndex, which is why I had the parameter index. Thank you!

Comment: I have updated answer, In which global variable x is updated within the function, but the name of the variable to be incremented is passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

When python calls `reset`, it gets a new reference to the value in `genreIndex` and passes that anonymous reference to the function. `reset` has no idea that the value came from `genreIndex`. Integers are immutable so changing `index` in the function creates a new object that cannot be assigned back to the global value without more information.

Assuming that you want `reset` to work with any number of lists and indexes, the normal way to solve this problem is by returning the new number. The caller knows which variable is which, and can assign appropriately.

```
genreIndex = 0
def reset(index, list):
    index = index + 1
    if index > (len(list) - 1):
        index = 0
    if index < 0:
        index = len(list)
    print(list[x])
    return index
    
genreIndex = reset(genreIndex, genreList)
genreIndex = reset(genreIndex, genreList)
genreIndex = reset(genreIndex, genreList)
```

You can also create a class that associates the index to a single genre list. Once the class is instantiated, its methods will no longer need explicit references to the index or the list

```
class Genre:

    def __init__(self, genre_list):
        self.genre_list = genre_list
        self.index = 0
        
    def reset(self):
        self.index += 1
        if self.index > (len(self.genre_list) - 1):
            self.index = 0
        if self.index < 0:
            self.index = len(self.genre_list)
        print(self.genre_list[self.index])
        
genre = Genre(genreList)
genre.reset()
genre.reset()
```